# How to draw a butterfly curve as accurate as possible?

Tags: java, 2d, graphics2d, java-2d

I am trying to draw a [butterfly curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_curve_(transcendental)) using `Java`.

Here's the parametric equation for the mentioned curve:

[image: Butterfly Curve Parametric equation]

From what I remember from the college, the way to draw a parametric equation with `Java` is the next:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.translate(300,300);
    int x1,y1;
    int x0 = 0;
    int y0 = (int)(Math.E-2); //for x = 0, we get y = Math.E - 2
    int nPoints = 1000;
    g2.scale(30,-30);
    for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
        double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints; //to make it between 0 and 12*PI.
        x1=(int)(Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        y1 = (int)(Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        g2.drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1);
        x0=x1;
        y0=y1;
    }
}
```

Now, this gave me the next result:

[image: first try curve]

Okay, this is so far away from the expected result.

I then decided to try it using `Line2D.Double` thinking that this would give a more accurate drawing.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.translate(300,300);
    double x1,y1;
    double x0 = 0;
    int nPoints = 500;
    g2.scale(30,-30);
    double y0 = Math.E-2;
    for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
        double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
        x1=(Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        y1 = (Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
        x0=x1;
        y0=y1;
    }
}
```

Which yielded the next result:

[image: Better curve]

Okay, this surely looks better, but not the expected result for sure.

Hence I am asking, is there a way to draw the most accurate curve using this parametric equation with `Java`?

[image: best curve]

It doesn't have to look 100% like the image above, but the closest.

Comment: You probably need to investiage [`CubicCurve2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/CubicCurve2D.html) and [`QuadCurve2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/QuadCurve2D.html) or just make use of [`Shape#quadTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html#quadTo(double,double,double,double)).  Or more generally, [bezier curves](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&q=bezier+curve&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFzOvN26zeAhXBMo8KHZGUCPIQBQgrKAA&biw=960&bih=913)

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, I'll make sure to check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scale-statement scales also the width of your line causing the strange shape of your curve. There are two easy ways to solve te problem:

1. Reduce the width of your line, e.g. to 0.01f:

   ```
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2.translate(300,300);
   double x1,y1;
   double x0 = 0;
   int nPoints = 500;
   // Alternative 1 ---------------------
   g2.scale(30,-30);
   g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.01f ));
   // -----------------------------------
   double y0 = Math.E-2;
   for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
       double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
       x1= (Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
       y1 = (Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
       g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
       x0=x1;
       y0=y1;
   }
   ```

This results in:

[image]

2. Remove your scale-statement and scale the curve using its amplitude i.e. use a constant prefactor concerning your x- and y-values, e.g. -30:

   ```
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2.translate(300,300);
   double x1,y1;
   double x0 = 0;
   int nPoints = 500;
   // Alternative 2 ---------------------
   double amp = -30.0;
   // -----------------------------------
   double y0 = Math.E-2;
   for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
       double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
       // Alternative 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       x1=amp*(Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
       y1=amp*(Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
       // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
       x0=x1;
       y0=y1;
   }
   ```

This results in (which is more or less identical):

[image]

Moreover you can enhance the quality of your plot by using an antialiasing and an increase of nPoints:

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    // Optimization ------------------------------------
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    int nPoints = 1500;
    // -------------------------------------------------
    g2.translate(300,300);
    double x1,y1;
    double x0 = 0;
    // Alternative 1 ---------------------
    g2.scale(50,-50);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.01f ));
    // -----------------------------------
    double y0 = Math.E-2;
    for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
        double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
        x1= (Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        y1 = (Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
        x0=x1;
        y0=y1;
    }
```

This results in (which looks much better):

[image]

So far, the connection between two points is a straight line. Sure, you can use splines (Bezier etc.) for further optimization, but probably that is not trivial.

Comment: Great catch. I didn't know that the stroke is affected by the scaling. It all makes sense now.