# How to draw a butterfly curve multiple times with different scale and translation using a single/simple for loop?

Tags: java, 2d, graphics2d, java-2d

This question is related to [my older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53054837/6783663).

What I am trying to do is to draw that same butterfly curve up to 30 times. Each time with a random scale/translation/color.

I tried this code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    for (int j=0;j<30;j++) {

        double tr = Math.random() * 300;
        g2.translate(tr,tr);
        double sc = Math.random() * 50 + 10;
        g2.scale(sc,sc);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.01f ));
        g2.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255),(int) (Math.random()*255)));
        double x1,y1;
        double x0 = 0;
        int nPoints = 1500;
        double y0 = Math.E-2;

        for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
            double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
            x1=(Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
            y1 = (Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
            x0=x1;
            y0=y1;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, at the end, it will only show/draw one curve. It won't show more than one. Since painting in Swing is destructive, I suspected that the problem I am facing have something to do with these lines being inside the for loop:

```
double tr = Math.random() * 300;
g2.translate(tr,tr);
double sc = Math.random() * 50 + 10;
g2.scale(sc,sc);
```

For a quick test, I tried this code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    double tr = Math.random() * 300;
    g2.translate(tr,tr);
    double sc = Math.random() * 50 + 10;
    g2.scale(sc,sc);

    for (int j=0;j<30;j++) {
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.01f ));
        g2.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255),(int) (Math.random()*255)));
        double x1,y1;
        double x0 = 0;
        int nPoints = 1500;
        double y0 = Math.E-2;
        g2.drawLine(5,j,100,j);
    }
}
```

This drew 30 lines, and when I added the `scale` and `translate` methods inside the loop, it only drew 1 line. *So I guess that I am right*.

**Can a simple for loop do the job or should I be going with a bit of more complex algorithm to draw that butterfly curve multiple times while changing scale and translation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using [AffineTransform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) to scale and translate.

Basically, the solution was to get rid of `g2.scale` and `g2.translate`, and use `g2.setTransform(tx);`. `tx` being an `AffineTransform` which scales and translates.

Here's the code that did it for me:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    for (int j=0;j<30;j++) {
        double sc = Math.random() * 30 + 10;
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.scale(sc, sc);
        tx.translate(Math.random() * 50, Math.random() * 50);
        g2.setTransform(tx);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.01f ));
        g2.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random()*255), (int)(Math.random()*255),(int) (Math.random()*255)));
        double x1,y1;
        double x0 = 0;
        int nPoints = 1500;
        double y0 = Math.E-2;

        for(int i=0;i<nPoints;i++) {
            double t= 12*i*Math.PI/nPoints;
            x1=(Math.sin(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
            y1 = (Math.cos(t)*(Math.pow(Math.E,Math.cos(t))-2*Math.cos(4*t)-Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12),5)));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0,y0,x1,y1));
            x0=x1;
            y0=y1;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Butterfly Images]

Comment: sᴍᴏʟ tip: `Math.pow(Math.E, [expr]) --> Math.exp([expr])`.